# python script that remove if's from another py script

Tags: python

So i wanna make a if block remover in python. I have a large python code made from many python files, where i have many if `ENABLE_THIS_CODE:` and it's hard to remove manual.

What i have already done:

```
import os
import re

def process_file(file_path):
    with open(file_path, 'r', encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore') as file:
        lines = file.readlines()

    modified_lines = []
    inside_enable_growth_pet_system = False

    for line in lines:
        if "ENABLE_GROWTH_PET_SYSTEM" in line and "if" in line:
            inside_enable_growth_pet_system = True
            continue  # Skip the entire line

        if inside_enable_growth_pet_system:
            if line.strip() == "":
                # Ignore empty lines inside the block
                inside_enable_growth_pet_system = False
                continue
            # Skip the entire line
            continue

        modified_lines.append(line)

    with open(file_path, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        file.writelines(modified_lines)

def process_directory(directory_path):
    for foldername, subfolders, filenames in os.walk(directory_path):
        for filename in filenames:
            if filename.endswith(".py"):
                file_path = os.path.join(foldername, filename)
                process_file(file_path)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    folder_path = "client/pack/root/"  # Change this to the desired folder path
    process_directory(folder_path)`
```

The above code works, but not as it should.
For example sometimes remove what is right, sometimes remove more than need, sometimes remove less than need.

For example i have this code:

```
`if app.ENABLE_12ZI:
    import ui12zi
    
if app.ENABLE_GROWTH_PET_SYSTEM:
    import uiPetInfo 
if app.ENABLE_MOVE_COSTUME_ATTR:
    import uiItemCombination
    
if app.ENABLE_PRIVATESHOP_SEARCH_SYSTEM:
    import uiPrivateShopSearch
`
```

When processing should become:

```
`if app.ENABLE_12ZI:
    import ui12zi

if app.ENABLE_MOVE_COSTUME_ATTR:
    import uiItemCombination
    
if app.ENABLE_PRIVATESHOP_SEARCH_SYSTEM:
    import uiPrivateShopSearch`
```

But instead it will remove both

```
if app.ENABLE_GROWTH_PET_SYSTEM:
    import uiPetInfo 
if app.ENABLE_MOVE_COSTUME_ATTR:
    import uiItemCombination
```

Comment: Why do you do this at all? I think you can save your time and not do it.

Comment: I told in question, i have over 100 python files.. when i have many if ENABLE_12ZI and many many that needs removed and it's hard to do it manual

Comment: I meant, why do you want to remove these parts. You could just execute the code with these parts, as long as the corresponding `app.ENABLE...` flags are not true.

Comment: because it's dead code, or unimplemented and i have many codess.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it's removing both right now is because of the condition you're checking to see if you exit the if block.

```
if inside_enable_growth_pet_system:
    if line.strip() == "":
        # Ignore empty lines inside the block
        inside_enable_growth_pet_system = False
        continue
    # Skip the entire line
    continue
```

Notice that your example of:

```
if app.ENABLE_12ZI:
    import ui12zi
    
if app.ENABLE_GROWTH_PET_SYSTEM:
    import uiPetInfo 
if app.ENABLE_MOVE_COSTUME_ATTR:
    import uiItemCombination
    
if app.ENABLE_PRIVATESHOP_SEARCH_SYSTEM:
    import uiPrivateShopSearch
```

has the target, `if app.ENABLE_GROWTH_PET_SYSTEM:`, but the next line where `line.strip == ""` would be true isn't until after the `if app.ENABLE_MOVE_COSTUME_ATTR:` ends.

Indentation will be a better way to check for blocks.

## Other methods

### Regex

```
import os
import re

def process_file(file_path):
    with open(file_path, 'r', encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore') as file:
        content = file.read()

    pattern = re.compile(r'if app\.ENABLE_GROWTH_PET_SYSTEM:(.*?)\n(?=\w|$)', re.DOTALL)
    modified_content = re.sub(pattern, '', content)

    with open(file_path, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        file.write(modified_content)

def process_directory(directory_path):
    for foldername, subfolders, filenames in os.walk(directory_path):
        for filename in filenames:
            if filename.endswith(".py"):
                file_path = os.path.join(foldername, filename)
                process_file(file_path)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    folder_path = "client/pack/root/"  # Change this to the desired folder path
    process_directory(folder_path)
```

### Replace

1. VSCode Shortcut to replace all instances of search text: `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `H`
2. Use a regex expression to match the if block, and replace it with an empty string

`if app.ENABLE_GROWTH_PET_SYSTEM:.*(.|\n).*`

[Image in VSCode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0MKDC.png)